# Agrandar imágenes con onclick

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

tengo el siguiente inconveniente traigo de una base de datos 4 imágenes que se corresponden con una fecha, si bien las trae y las muestra necesito que al hacer click se agrande en el centro de la pagina y al hacer doble click vuelva al tamaño en el que estaba. adjunto CSS y contenedor HTML donde muestra las imágenes. se puede con alguna función en javascript. Desde ya muchas gracias. Edite el código en el post y la primer imagen se agranda pero queda por debajo de las otras si observan el código de la primer imagen tiene agregado alt="imagen" ondblclick="this.style.height = '800px'[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  <style>
    
    #centrador{
      text-align: center;
    
    
    }
    
    .imagenf{
        position: absolute;
        width: 340px;
        height: 340px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 10px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    
    
    </style>
```

// adjunto HTMl donde muestro las cuatro imágenes

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 290px; width:240px">
        <h3 class="card-title">Imagen </h3>
        <a class="thumbnail">
         <p id="centrador"><img alt="imagen" ondblclick="this.style.height = '800px'; this.style.width = '1000px'; this.style.position = 'absolute';  " onClick="this.style.height = '340px'; this.style.width = '340px';" name ="imagen0" id="imagen0" class="imagenf" src='<?php if (isset($nombre[0])) {echo $nombre[0];} else {echo $sinimage;}?>' >
  </p>
        </a>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 290px; width:240px">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Imagen </h3>
        <a  class="thumbnail">
          <p id="centrador"><img onclick="javascript:this.width=450;this.height=338" ondblclick="javascript:this.width=100;this.height=80" name ="imagen1" id="imagen1" class="imagenf" src='<?php if (isset($nombre[1])) {echo $nombre[1];} else {echo $sinimage;}?>' ></p>
        </a>
    </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 290px; width:240px">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Imagen </h3>
        <a  class="thumbnail" >
          <p id="centrador"><img onclick="javascript:this.width=450;this.height=338" ondblclick="javascript:this.width=100;this.height=80" class="imagenf" name ="imagen2" id="imagen2" src='<?php if (isset($nombre[2])) {echo $nombre[2];} else {echo $sinimage;}?>' ></p>
        </a>
    </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 290px; width:240px">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Imagen </h3>
        <a  class="thumbnail" >
          <p id="centrador" >
            <img onclick="javascript:this.width=450;this.height=338" ondblclick="javascript:this.width=100;this.height=80"  class="imagenf" name ="imagen3" id ="imagen3" src='<?php if (isset($nombre[3])) {echo $nombre[3];} else {echo $sinimage;}?>'>
    
    
          </p>
        </a>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola, y que has intentado para obtener el efecto de que cuando le des click cambie el tamaño???

Comment: No se ve ningún código javascript con el cual empezar a trabajar. Lo mínimo sería un esqueleto del .js capaz de capturar los clicks. Revisa este documento: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Con este JQuery conseguirías hacerlo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("ul").on('dbclick', '#pop', function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
   });
});
```

Crea un modal html que tenga la imagen oculto en todo momento, que se vea solo con haces doble click.